# Matlab- how can I change an array since it is seen as double

Tags: arrays, matlab, double, cell

I need to iterate Newton-Raphson.The problem is:

For mmm=1:

1) If m=1 take c1=c1b and c2=1-c1 and do the loop for u1,2(i) and p1,2(i)

2)If m=2 take c1=c1+dc and c2=1-c1, and this time do the loop with new c1 and c2 for u1,2(i) and p1,2(i)

3) If m=3 take c1=(c1*st(1)-(c1-dc)*st(2))/(st(1)-st(2)) and do the loop for new c1 and c2.

Then increase the iteration number: mmm=2 ;

mmm keeps count of the number of N-R iterations. The first iteration has mmm=1, the second mmm=2, etc. (This particular run only do 2 iterations).

sumint are inside of the integrals. 'c1, c2 are the camber effects, u1 u2 are the velocities, p1 p2 are pressures.

Relevant part of the code:

```
ii=101;
 ub = cell(2, 1);
    ini_cond = [0,0]; 
    for i = 1:2;
           ub{i} = zeros(1,ii);
           ub{i}(:, ii) = ini_cond(i) * rand(1, 1);
    end    

    for i=1:ii;
           x=i*dx;
              fikness = fik*sin(pi.*x);
              ub{1}(i) = (c1b-H1D*(x-0.5)+AD/2.*(x-0.5).^2)./(H1-0.5*fikness-A*(x-0.5));
              ub{2}(i) = (c2b+H1D*(x-0.5)-AD/2.*(x-0.5).^2)./(1.-H1+0.5*fikness+A*(x-0.5));
    end   
    mmm = 1;
    c1 = c1b;
    m = 1;
    c2=1-c1;
    u = cell(2, 1);
    ini_cond = [0,0];
    for i = 1:2;
       u{i} = zeros(1,ii);
       u{i}(:, ii) = ini_cond(i) * rand(1, 1);
    end    

    for i=1:ii;
       x=(i-1)*dx;
       fikness = fik*sin(pi.*x);
       u{1}(i) = (c1-H1D*(x-0.5)+AD/2.*(x-0.5).^2)./(H1-0.5*fikness-A*(x-0.5));
       u{2}(i)= (c2+H1D*(x-0.5)-AD/2.*(x-0.5).^2)./(1.-H1+0.5*fikness+A*(x-0.5)); 
    end

    p = cell(2, 1);
    q = cell(2, 1);

    for i = 1:2;
       p{i} = zeros(1,100);
       q{i} = zeros(1,100);
    end    

    p{1}(1) = 0.5*(1.-u{1}(1).^2);
    q{1}(1) = 0;
    p{2}(1) = 0.5*(1.-u{2}(1).^2);
    q{2}(1) = 0;

    for i = 2:ii;
        q{1}(i) = q{1}(i-1)-dx*(u{1}(i-1)-ub{1}(i-1))./dt;    
        p{1}(i) = 0.5*(1.-u{1}(i).^2)+q{1}(i);    
        q{2}(i) = q{2}(i-1)-dx*(u{2}(i-1)-ub{2}(i-1))./dt;    
        p{2}(i) = 0.5*(1.-u{2}(i).^2)+q{2}(i);    
    end

    st = zeros(2, 1);
    st(1,:) = p{1}(100)-p{2}(100);
   m = m+1;

    if m==3; 
      c1=(c1*st(1)-(c1-dc)*st(2))/(st(1)-st(2));
      c2=1-c1;
  end

    sumint = cell(2, 1);
    for i = 1:2    
       sumint{i} = zeros(1,length(x));    
    end 

    sumint{1}(1) = 0.5*(p{2}(1)-p{1}(1));
    sumint{2}(1) = 0.5*(p{2}(1)-p{1}(1)).*(-1/2);

    for i = 2:100;
      x=(i-1)*dx;
      sumint{1}(i) = sumint{1}(i-1)+(p{2}(i)-p{1}(i));    
      sumint{2}(i) = sumint{2}(i-1)+(p{2}(i)-p{1}(i)).*(x-1/2);
    end
```

The error is: ??? Attempted to access u.%cell(2); index out of bounds because numel(u.%cell)=1.

Error in ==> grab3_SmithWilson at 75 p{1}(i)=0.5*(1.-u{1}(i).^2)+q{1}(i);

Comment: Please post runnable code. There are many things undefined here

Comment: Also show more clearly what exactly you expect to see. An easy way debug and see the first row of `ub{2}` would be to do `u = ub{2}`, then you don't need to worry about the cell array.

Comment: I suspect you want to access the array of zeroes you put into each cell. You should read about [accessing parts of cells](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/multilevel-indexing-to-access-parts-of-cells.html) if that's the case. The reason `ub{1}` has a single value is because you've overwritten the array you initially put there; try `ub{1}(1) = ...` to access the first element of the array stored in the first element of the cell.

Comment: Yes ub{1}(1) is shown above coz I see from the matlab prompt. What I cannot see is ub{2}(1) it says 1*101 double instead of its value. Could you help me please

Comment: @user3115779 You did not type `ub{2}(1)` or else you would see `0` (before the loop runs) or `0.9750` after the loop runs. Please read the link I posted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to show us what you want to see. When I run the code you posted now, I find that first `ub` is printed as you have written, then **each cell of `ub` is overwritten on each loop iteration**. What I mean is that you are not putting values into the arrays that are stored in the cells, you are putting values in to the cells themselves. Are you sure that's what you want?

If you want to store the calculation in the elements of the arrays that are stored in the cells, the following will work:

```
for i=1:ii;
x=(i-1)*dx;
        fikness=fik*sin(pi.*x);
        ub{1}(i)=(c1b-H1D*(x-0.5)+AD/2*(x-0.5)^2)/(H1-0.5*fikness-A*(x-0.5));
        ub{2}(i)=(c2b+H1D*(x-0.5)-AD/2*(x-0.5)^2)/(1-H1+0.5*fikness+A*(x-0.5));

end

>> ub

ub = 

    [1x101 double]
    [1x101 double]
```

This is why I suggested reading about [accessing parts of cells](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/multilevel-indexing-to-access-parts-of-cells.html). Really though, this is just a guess until you tell us what you want from your script.

Comment: You are saving me from a trouble thanks for that. Little quaestion : why    ub{1}(ii) I mean why the last term you enter the system ? I am new to Matlab as you see . Apologies for disturbing

Comment: Is it supposed to be i instead of ii such as ub{1}(i) ??

Comment: "Apologies for disturbing" No need to apologize :-) Most people here are happy to help, but you have to help us help you. In your questions, you should please explain exactly **what you want to get** and what you are actually getting.

Comment: Actually the whole problem is huge these values are velocities u1 and u2 they take values according to lateral position x. and similarly I can write the pressures p1 and p2. But the problem is I want to see their values I mean for example u1 (30) ? or u2(90)? now when i debug these rows as you show it says 1*101 double

Comment: Please see edit. this becomes out of topic I konw but the whole problem I am just trying to change the values of velocity and pressure according to changing c1 and c2 s.

Comment: @user3115779 Please do not change the question like that. Furthermore, you have already asked this question several times. Please give people some time to respond. Please undo the changes you have made to this question. The reason is, when someone comes to look at this page in the future, they will see your question and my answer and it will not make sense because you changed the question. Again, please ask a new question and revert the edits you made to this question. I don't think I can help you further on this question.